# System Monitor Script

Tags: bash, scripts

I created a simple script written in bash to constantly monitor my system temp and RAM free.

```
    while :
        do
        clear;
        echo "---------------------------RAM Load------------------------------$
        free -mt;
        echo "---------------------------Temperature---------------------------$
        sensors;
        sleep 1;
        clear;
done
```

I was wondering if it is possible to write this data to a simple text file, or worksheet thingy, for use with [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You can just redirect output of `free` and `sensors` to a file:

```
free -mt >> memoryfile.txt
```

Using `>>` will append rather than overwrite the file.

That said, you may be reinventing the wheel here. Existing tools such as [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) can simply be installed, some plugins enabled, and they will periodically monitor your system parameters to produce a graph and store them in a database. Presumably extracting data from this database to use it with dygraphs would be easier than devising a parser to massage raw output from `sensors` and `free`; well, that's not inherently difficult but as I say, it's already done in munin plugins.

Comment: "That said, you may be reinventing the wheel here." I am trying to get some code experience, so doing it myself is the right way

Comment: Way to go! in that case you may find this reference useful: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html Good luck!

Comment: can you also help with the next step? http://askubuntu.com/questions/420870/temperature-ram-monitoring-script