# Temperature & RAM monitoring script

Tags: bash, scripts, webserver

I have the following script:

```
    while :
 do
        clear;
        echo "---------------------------RAM Load------------------------------$
        free -mt >> memory.txt;
        free -mt;
        echo "---------------------------Temperature---------------------------$
        sensors >> temp.txt;
        sensors;
        sleep 1;
        clear;
done
```

which gets the current system RAM and temperature and writes it to two files, respectively memory.txt and temp.txt

I want to use this data on a webserver with [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com)
what is the best way to clean up the data, because it gives these two file:

[memory.txt](http://p.tpps.cf/view/7a5722b6)
[temp.txt](http://p.tpps.cf/view/8c72dd66)

for the RAM part I only want the `-/+ buffers/cache:` line
and from the temperature part only the temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to solve this issue by using `grep`.

To get just the `-/+ buffers/cache` line, alter your `free` commands to this:

```
free -mt | grep buffers/cache >> memory.txt;
free -mt | grep buffers/cache;
```

To get only the temperatures try:

```
sensors | grep °C >> temp.txt;
sensors | grep °C;
```

So using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear;
echo "---------------------------RAM Load------------------------------$"
free -mt | grep buffers/cache >> memory.txt;
free -mt | grep buffers/cache;
echo "---------------------------Temperature---------------------------$"
sensors | grep °C >> temp.txt;
sensors | grep °C;
```

Produces this output:

```
---------------------------RAM Load------------------------------$
-/+ buffers/cache:       1545        449
---------------------------Temperature---------------------------$
Physical id 0:      N/A  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:             N/A  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Physical id 2:      N/A  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:             N/A  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
aploetz@dockingBay94:~$
```

For removing the extra text that you don't want, you could try using `awk`.

```
$ free -mt | grep buffers/cache | awk '{print $3"\t"$4}'
1588    406
```

The temperatures will be a bit trickier, but can be done with `tr`.

```
$ sensors | grep Physical | tr -d '(),' | awk '{print $7"\t"$10}'
+100.0°C    +100.0°C
+100.0°C    +100.0°C

$sensors | grep Core | tr -d '(),' | awk '{print $6"\t"$9}'
+100.0°C    +100.0°C
+100.0°C    +100.0°C
```

If you wanted to get rid of the plusses as well, just add '+' to the delete flag:

```
$ sensors | grep Core | tr -d '(),+' | awk '{print $6"\t"$9}'
100.0°C 100.0°C
100.0°C 100.0°C
```

Comment: nice answer, but can I also remove the -/+ buffers/cache text and the same with the temperature, for use with Dygraph, as I stated?

Comment: Sure try `free -mt |grep buffers/cache  |sed 's/^.\+ buffers\/cache: \+//' >> temp.txt`, this will just output the two numbers.

Comment: @roadmr and for the temperature? And is there anyway I can also get the current time for a Dygraph graph?

Comment: @Rumanoid edit made.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bryce's good advice, there's no need to run the command twice:

```
free -mt | grep buffers/cache | tee -a memory.txt
sensors | grep °C | tee -a temp.txt
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done!  I forgot all about `tee`.